# How to load AdMob Ads during App Store review?

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, app-store

How can `release` builds of an iOS app be configured to allow the App Store review team to load AdMob ads?

AdMob rewarded video ads load correctly in "Test mode" when running `debug` builds, but when building for `release` on a physical device the following error is presented:

> Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
>  To get test ads on this device, set:
> Objective-C
> GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"EXAMPLE-STRING" ];
> Swift
> GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ "EXAMPLE-STRING" ]

Also from the AdMob developer documentation:

> iOS simulators are automatically configured as test devices.

Adding the Swift code listed above to the app, or adding my iPhone as a test device in the AdMob portal solved the issue for loading ads on my own physical device. But what about the **App Store review team**? Will adding the Swift code above allow them to see the ads?

Comment: The App Store review team do not run a test build. They run the release build of your app that will go to the store on a real device. Use a TestFlight build to see what they will see

Comment: Appreciate the comment. The App Store review team still won't be able to see the ads even in the TestFlight release build, which I have also tried. Ads only work if I add the Swift code `testDeviceIdentifiers`, or add the physical device to the list of Test Devices in the AdMob dashboard. Even running the TestFlight release build does not show ads. I'm very surprised there is no well documented solution for this, I cannot be the only one.

Comment: If you don't see ads in a testflight release then not only will the reviewers not see any ads, your users won't see any ads either. You haven't set up the ad framework correctly.  From an AdMob perspective a TestFlight build is the same as an app downloaded from the store.

Comment: My assumption was that if the release build is downloaded from the App Store, then ads will work. I'm not sure what else can be configured.

Comment: "New iOS apps will not show Google ads until they’re listed in the Apple App Store. ".  - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en Is this correct? The same app has been published in Google Play, and it was a similar scenario. The ads did not work until listed in the Play Store. But if the device was listed as a Test Device, the ads would show in "Test Mode".

Comment: Ok, well, if that is what Google says then the behaviour you are seeing is expected. The review team will not see ads, but that should not prevent your app from operating and should not affect your review

Comment: There is a loading screen that is displayed while the ad is pre-loaded. Because the ad cannot be loaded, the loading state is never set to false, so it just hangs on the loading screen indicator. This prevents the app from operating during review.

Comment: That is a bug that you need to fix then.  Your app should function even if ads cannot be loaded.  The user may be offline.  There may be some other network issue.  Your ad units may not be active yet...